# Of sorts vs A sort of

Tags: meaning

What basically is the difference (if any) between these two expressions - *of sorts* and *(a) sort of*

> He would wear a coat of sorts.
>
> He would wear a sort of coat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"A sort of coat" means a coat that's *something like a coat, but not quite*.

For example, if you pulled a t-shirt over your head to shield your hair from the rain, that would be "a sort of coat". It could also refer to any coat in general without being specific, but then it's better to dispense with the extra words and just say "a coat".

"A coat of sorts" is used for *a very unusual, strange, or substandard coat*.

For example, if you wore [a coat of human skin knitted together from your serial-killing victims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silence_of_the_Lambs_%28film%29), that would be "a coat of sorts", to put it mildly. Or if you couldn't afford a coat and stitched together old blankets to make a coat, that would also be a coat of sorts.

The difference is in the intention: your t-shirt isn't meant to be used as a coat, but it can be **like a coat, in the right circumstances**; it's a *a sort of coat*. By contrast, *a coat of sorts* is **meant to be a coat**, but it's bizarre or bad in some way.

Answer (score 2):

[Of sorts](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sort) is an idiom and can imply inferiority.

> of a sort
>
> (or of sorts)
>
> *informal* Of a somewhat unusual or inferior kind:
>
> *the training camp actually became a tourist attraction of sorts*

`A sort of coat` uses sort in the normal sense and is free of such implications.